# Linux: let a process fail, if it does opens a file for writing

Tags: linux, system-calls, cgroups

I would like a command-line-tool to fail if it opens a particular file for writing.

Is there a way I can modify the environment (maybe via cgroups) of the command-line tool, so that the command/process gets (for example) "permission denied"?

`chmod a-w file` does not work. The process seems to `unlink()` and then re-create the file.

I know that I can watch the syscalls of a process with `strace`. But is there a way to alter some calls, so that the process gets a different result?

## Background: unittesting

Comment: maybe run the process in some overlay fs with modified permission?

Comment: @PrzemysławCzechowski I would like to work on the syscall level: I know that I can watch the syscalls of a process with strace. But is there a way to alter some calls, so that the process gets a different result?

Comment: `strace` has an `--inject` option, that seems like what you're looking for

Comment: @perivesta `inject` of `strace` is exactly the solution I was looking for. Please create an answer and I will up-vote and accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strace` has an option called `-e inject` or simply `--inject` which can be used to alter system calls of the tracee. ([See manpage here](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html))

In particular, in can be combined with the `-P` option to only trace syscalls accessing a specified path.

Answer (score 1):

Since the calls are honored in the order they are loaded from shared libraries, you can use LD_PRELOAD to load a custom library prior to the system libraries and hijack their execution. This is used by many network card accelerators like OpenOnload from Solarflare/Xilinx.

https://sumit-ghosh.com/articles/hijacking-library-functions-code-injection-ld-preload/